# VBA, function not returning value

Tags: excel, vba, function

I made a simple function to validate the user's input.

```
Function isNumber(sen As String)
Do Until Val(i) = CDbl(Val(i)) And IsNumeric(i) And i <> ""
      i = Application.InputBox(sen)
Loop
End Function
```

then used the following to call the function:

```
Public Sub test()
testing = isNumber("test")
Debug.Print (testing)
End Sub
```

For some reasons, no value is being returned. i.e., nothing in the immediate window.

Comment: Your `isNumber` function doesn't return anything... it needs an `isNumber = ...`.

Comment: Also drop the parentheses: `Debug.Print testing`.

Comment: It is necessary to assign the result to a function name: `isNumber = <expression>`. Read [Function statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement)

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! it worked!